# How to disable angular library dependency?

Tags: angularjs, typescript, bootstrap-datetimepicker, angular-bootstrap, jspm

I'm working on a project using `TypeScript`, `AngularJS`, `ES6` and `JSPM`. I have some libraries, including of course AngularJS and some other that depend on AngularJS, like `angular-bootstrap-datetimepicker`.

The problem I have is `angular-bootstrap-datetimepicker` trying to load angular again. I get this warning:

> WARNING: Tried to load angular more than once.

After some research I was able to "solve" the problem by editing my `config.js` file to:

```
'npm:angular-bootstrap-datetimepicker@0.4.0': {
  // 'angular': 'npm:angular@1.4.8', 
  'moment': 'npm:moment@2.11.0'
},
```

If I uncomment that line the warning comes back. I know that's not a solution, since any npm updates would override my changes there and also other libraries could do the same thing. So does anyone know how can I disable these dependencies the "right way"?

Thanks.

**EDIT:**

```
'use strict';

import 'angular';
import 'jquery';
import * as _ from 'lodash';
import appData     from '../app.data/module';
import appCore     from '../app.core/module';
import appInstance from '../app.instance/module';

export default angular.module('app', [
  appData.name,
  appCore.name,
  appInstance.name
]);

angular.bootstrap(document.documentElement, ['app']);
```

**EDIT 2:**

```
'use strict';

export default function RouteConfig($urlRouterProvider): void {
  // apply consistent trailing slashes and casing
    $urlRouterProvider.rule(function ($injector, $location) {

      var path = $location.path(),
        search = $location.search(),
        newPath,
        params;

      if (path === '/') {
        newPath = '/';
      }

      if (path[path.length - 1] === '/') {
        newPath = path.substring(0, path.length - 1);
      } else {
        newPath = path;
      }

      if (Object.keys(search).length > 0) {
        params = [];
        angular.forEach(search, function (v, k) {
          params.push(k + '=' + v);
        });

        newPath += '?' + params.join('&');
      }

      newPath = newPath.toLowerCase();

      if ($location.url() === newPath) {
        return;
      }

      $location.replace().path(newPath);
    });

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
}
```

Comment: Please post your head and angular init code. I have a suspicion that it's your string concats or tag closures that are causing this. As is typical with that warning message, angular can't find a resource due to these problems and tries to load the root '/' in your 'otherwise'  statement, therefore loading index.html etc again.

Comment: @JohnValai Sure, thanks for your comment, please check my edit.